# How to display the data to view from controller in asp.net MVC (Serial Communication)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serial-port

I am trying to build a login system using Arduino and RFID reader in asp.net MVC c#.

My objective is to update my view from the controller every time the client taps his RFID tag to RFID reader. Whenever the client taps his RFID tag to RFID reader, I want to update the view to display the information of the client.

For now, I am able to read the tag ID from Arduino using the code below but I don't have an idea on how to display my data to view. I did searching for this problem in google but I didn't get the answer for asp.net.

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace read_rfid_example.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");

            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;

            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

            if(!mySerialPort.IsOpen)
                 mySerialPort.Open();


            return View();
        }

        private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                         object sender,
                         SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
            Console.Write(indata);

            Debug.WriteLine(indata); //  TAG ID: 03 0e 03 06 (output example and want to pass this data to view)
        }
      }
    }
```

**Simple View**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h3>@ViewBag.TagId</h3>
```

My problem and my question are how can I update my  tag in view every time the RFID reader detects the RFID tag? I need help with this problem. Someone can give me a proper way to make this like real-time?

Comment: why mvc? in your case maybe should try with winforms. If you select mvc so you should install rfid reader in web server or create an winservice for interact with the web page. You can create js code for infinite loop and check new cards but it will be some strange. I can only imagine a scenario for what you are saying, a kiosk

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Of some reason, my instructor recommended it to me that I'll use c# asp.net for this project. I have no idea that serial Port communication is hard to implement in asp.net so I accepted it. Now, all forum that I've visited regarding this issue, their answer was the same. Serial Port communication is not recommended for asp.net.  Sad but I can't go back to scratch because of limited time.

Answer (score 0):

if you want see some maybe could be like

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                     object sender,
                     SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
        Console.Write(indata);
        Session["RfidCurrent"] = indata;
        Debug.WriteLine(indata); //  TAG ID: 03 0e 03 06 (output example and want to pass this data to view)
    }


    [HttpGet] 
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.TagId = Session["RfidCurrent"]
        return View();
    }
```